# Using replace scene to navigate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a question with regards to using replace scene in cocos2d.

Assume my game menu has the following structure:

1. Main Menu
2. Play
   2.1 Strategy levels
   2.2 Accuracy levels
3. Settings
4. Tutorial

Is the recommended method of navigation between the menus, "replace scene" or "push/pop"?

I've read in some places that its good to avoid push/pop in cocos2d. But my concern in using replace scene is that i have the impression that im just stacking up scenes instead of having a proper navigational flow.

Answer (score 0):

Push and pop scene is going to stack your scenes. Each time you push a new scene, the old scene remains in memory and you need the exact same amount of popScene to get back to the initial scene.

So yes, using replaceScene is the standard and recommended method of switching scenes. While replaceScene removes the original scene from memory, there is a short time of overlap where both scenes remain in memory. So if you have two very memory intensive scenes, it is recommended to go through a temporary loading scene instead to allow the previous scene enough time to release its memory.

Note also that you cannot call replaceScene within the init method of a scene. That will cause CCDirector to crash.

Comment: I have 2 question , Can you explain how much items we can render on Loading Scene. if the loading scene is heavy then obviously loading scene will also consume some extra memory. .So I guess ideally a loading scene should at-least have a CCSPrite Background and a Label "Loading.....". Is that correct? 
My second question is how to calculate how much assets are there in total , and how to calculate how is loaded. Basically looking for a pre-loader like how we have in Flash games (Loading Bar length from 0 to 100 px with % information) .